# Android -Connection Error

Tags: android, http

I need to parse the link given below

```
http://192.168.1.91/projects/gprs/
```

If I open this in my browser i get like the response given below,

```
 {"machine":[{"id":"3688","machine_code":"999999","di1":"0","di2":"1","di3":"0","di4":"1","di5":"0","di6":"1","di7":"0","di8":"1"}]}
```

But In my project ,logcat shows connection refused

I need to get the values in textview .How to achieve this?

The java codings is pasted below,

**AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java**

```
 public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// url to make request
private static String url = "http://192.168.1.91/projects/gprs/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "machine";
private static final String TAG_ID = "di1";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "di2";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "di3";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "di4";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "di5";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "di5";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "di7";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "di8";
//private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
            String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
            String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
            String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });



}

}
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: you should paste your code.

Comment: Did u give permission to access internet in your manifest file?

Comment: yes,I've given the permission @Mayu Mayooresan

Comment: Your code seems right. Check your internet permission in manifest and better you implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to parse your data. This [](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) might be useful.

Comment: Why you no post the `logcat` trace?

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to parse your response:

```
public void parseHttpResponse(String response){
    JSONObject object;
    try {
        object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("machine");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id=c.getString("id");
            String machineCode=c.getString("machine_code");
            //so as parse other
            Log.v(TAG, "id: "+id+" machine code: "+machineCode);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Use :**

```
parseHttpResponse("your_response_here");
```